# Flare3D Flex Context3D issue

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, flare3d

I have followed step by step the instruction to build the Flare3D examples at this url
http://www.flare3d.com/blog/2011/03/10/flare3d-2-0-startup-with-flash-builder/

and I fixed the wmode to direct in my html template for the actionscript project, but when it comes to building the examples from the 5th Flex refuses to compile since there are errors in the project.
The errors are these ones:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4064417/FlareProblems.jpg

Do you have any idea on how to fix them? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The guide I linked is old!
Since I was using Flash Builder 4.6 I just went to Project > Properties > ActionScript Compiler and selected Flex 4.6 sdk!

This made all the errors disappear.

The problem was that display3d exists only in flashplayer 11 and the guide was telling me to select 10.2 which is WRONG!

Hope this will be helpful for others as well!